# Ansible optional variable in configuration file

Tags: ansible, jinja2

In the configuration file of the service I want to configure, I have an optional parameter which can be completely omitted. The templating language for my configuration file is Jinja2.

What I want is to be able to define a variable in my Ansible `vars.yml` file:

```
optional_service_parameter: "value"
```

Whenever the variable is defined in `vars.yml` I want to use it in the service configuration:

```
config:
  parameter1: {{ parameter_var_1 }} 
  parameter2: {{ parameter_var_2 }}
  optional_parameter: {{ optional_service_parameter }}
```

When the variable `optional_service_parameter` is not set in `vars.yml`, the `optional_service_parameter` should be omitted in my service configuration file. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `when` condition with `lookup` of variable. Below is the example. I have used set_facts with when condition to keep it simple. If the variable is found then it will print the message else it will not print. Hope this helps.

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: testing
      debug:
        msg: "{{ optional_service_parameter }}"
      when: lookup('vars', 'optional_service_parameter', errors='ignore', default=false)
```